# Creating a LSTM network which outputs a single probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, deep-learning, lstm

I am new to LSTM and tensorflow and would like to build an LSTM network to classify behaviour based on the last 30 days of activity. My dataset is made up of mobile subscriber data (6 real-valued variables per day) for the last 30 days. It also has an indicator field stating whether they are active or not at end of the 30 days. I would like to predict the probability that they are active after 30 days. Can you assist with any of following:

1. Direct me to some sample code which I can use to learn how to solve my problem.
2. Advise on some literature which would be beneficial to learning LSTM in tensorflow.
3. Any other helpful suggestion.

Comment: The question is too broad, please reformulate in a more coincise way.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like you are pretty new in the world of neural networks it might be a good idea to look at some courses. That said, also take a look at Keras: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/ . It allows you to easily experiment a bit to see what works or does not work. Some code that roughly does what you want is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(30, 6))) # hidden state with 10 units
model.add(Dense(2)) # two classes: active, not active
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Hope this helps you a bit on your way into the world of neural networks!